# Static-Methods and what to do with them

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, mockito

When writing some Unit-tests I found out, that we use a lot of static method-calls from Utility-classes. Now with Mockito I can't mock the calls of them. So what would be the best approach?

I know wrote public methods, inside the class where I just return the static call. For example:

```
public String getName(File file){ return PDFUtil.getName(file); }
```

And then I call the public method inside the other method. And now I can mock the `getName()` method with Mockito with Spying.

However two things:

1. There's redundancy. I maybe use the `PDFUtil.getName(File)` method in other classes too, so I should only have one class and should only implement getName() once.
2. Let's consider I have like 4 different static method calls and extract them in 4 different methods. These are now methods I can't test. So is this ok, since it's said very easy methods like getters and setters shouldn't be tested?

Comment: "*Now* with Mockito I can't mock the calls of them." It would be a lot easier if you had written the tests first.

Comment: Why do you *need* to mock them? Do these methods do work that shouldn't be executed during tests?

Comment: Check out powermock / powermockito whichs has mockStatic ()

Comment: It might be a good idea to refactor the static utility methods that can't be used in unit tests into non-static methods of utility objects that can be injected into (preferably passed as an argument to the constructor of) the objects that need them.

Answer (score 0):

You can mock a static method directly using [PowerMock](https://github.com/jayway/powermock). Let's say you have this class:

```
public class StaticMethodClass {
   public String method() {
       return StaticMethodClass.staticMethod();
   }

   public static String staticMethod() {
      return "hello world";
   }
}
```

The unit test could look like this:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(StaticMethodClass.class)
public class UnitTest {

   @Test
   public void test() {
      PowerMockito.mockStatic(StaticMethodClass.class);
      PowerMock.when(StaticMethodClass.staticMethod()).thenReturn("yeah");

      assertEquals("yeah", new StaticMethodClass().method());
   }
}
```

Note: I didn't actually test this code. Take it as a hint :-)